# Including a source file in the root of project

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm attempting to include a source (.py) file in the root of the project which will be included to execute Linux DLLs (.so). So far I cannot include anything in the root directory of project unless it's for compilation.

I can easily include the file in the package but it ruins the structure as I cannot run executeCompiled.py in /somePackage/ which attempts to call compiled.so.

What I want the structure to look like:

```
/somePackage/someData.txt
compiled.so
executeCompiled.py
```

setup.py would look something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Compiler import Options

Options.docstrings = False
Options.embed = True

setup(
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = {'':'src'},
    package_data = {'somePackage': ['*.*']},
    ext_modules = cythonize("src/compiled.py", language_level=3),
)
```

### SOLUTION:

Adding the py file exclusively to package_data, previously I used '/executeCompiled.py' which meant the file was not found.

```
package_data = {'somePackage': ['*.*'], '': ['../executeCompiled.py']}
```

Comment: can you please post your setup.py or relevant parts from it?

Comment: do you want to call executeCompiled.py as part of the setup.py? or after the installation?

Comment: executeCompiled is meant to be kept as source to call the compiled file in the same dir.